# TestSuite vs "test discover"

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Is there any difference between creating a TestSuite and add to it all the TestCases, or just running `python -m unittest discover` in the TestCases directory?

For example, for a directory with two TestCases: `test_case_1.py` and `test_case_2.py`:

```
import unittest

from test_case_1 import TestCaseClass as test1
from test_case_2 import TestCaseClass as test2


suite = unittest.TestSuite()
suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(test1))
suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(test2))

unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

Or just `cd` into that directory and run `python -m unittest discover`.

I'm getting the same result with either way, but I'm interesting in knowing whether one way is preferred over the other, and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an obvious benefit in favor of `discover` is maintenance.

- After a month, you get rid of `test_case_2` - some of your code above will fail (the `import`) and you'll have to correct your above script. That's annoying, but not the end of the world.
- After two months, someone on your team made `test_case_3`, but was unaware that they need to add it to the script above. No tests fail, and everyone is happy - the problem is, nothing from `test_case_3` actually runs. However, you might counter that it's unreasonable to write new tests, and not notice that they're not running. This brings to the next scenario.
- Even worse - after three months, someone merges two versions of your above script, and `test_case_3` gets squeezed out again. This might go unnoticed. Until it's corrected, people can work all they want on the stuff that `test_case_3` is supposed to check, but it's just untested.

Comment: sounds a valid reason for getting rid of the TestSuite, bearing in mind that my superior "want to have" (I hope he actually doesn't mean it.. xD) over 1k tests xD

Comment: Good luck with your superior!